# Best approach to create different JSON response from same Entity

Tags: spring-boot

I have an entity class User with 20 fields, some of them being confidential fields. I have a controller class, which has a  method getUser to fetch all the user from DB and send the JSON respone. Below is the sample code for the same:

```
@GetMapping("/getUsers")
public UserDT getUsers( Model theModel) {

    List<User> userList;
    userList = userService.findAll();

    return userList;
}
```

When I run the above code, it returns all the fields from User table/User Entity Class. Instead of sending all the fields, I would like to send selected fields say Field1 to Field5 only.

Ultimate goal is to have multiple views for the same Entity Class. For URL1 I would like to show only field1 to field5 of User table, But for URL2 I would like to show Field9 , Filed15, Field20.

Do I need to create multiple Entity Class for each URL? Please guide me with the best practice to be followed in such scenario.

Comment: A good start would be the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections). Especially [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Data JPA, use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

So create different projections for your different URLs write a method that returns the projection (or a [dynamic one](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projection.dynamic) as in the documentation).

```java
public interface NamesOnlyProjection {

  String getFirstName();
  String getLastName();

}
```

```java
public interface UserinfoProjection {

  String getUsername();
  String getPassword();
  String getDepartment();
}
```

Then in your repository do something like this

```java
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {


  <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> type);

}
```

Then you can do something like this in your controller/service

```java
@RestController
public class PersonController {

  private final PersonRepository persons;

  @GetMapping("/people/names")
  public List<NamesOnlyProjection> allNames() {
    return persons.findAll(NamesOnlyProjection.class);
  }  

  @GetMapping("/people/users")
  public List<UserinfoProjection> allNames() {
    return persons.findAll(UserinfoProjection.class);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum. Its helpful. One more question,  In which folder do we keep these interaces  as best practice.

Comment: That isn't a question I'm going to answer as that is strongly opinionated .